# Redis issue with snapshot - Error moving temp DB file on the final destination: Operation not permitted

Tags: redis, sensu

I've a working setup with redis and sensu. Suddenly I'm getting redis server issue while its trying to take RDB snapshots.

```
[2830] 27 Dec 06:25:50.648 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[2830] 27 Dec 06:25:50.649 * Background saving started by pid 24929
[24929] 27 Dec 06:25:50.670 # Error moving temp DB file on the final destination: Operation not permitted
[2830] 27 Dec 06:25:50.750 # Background saving error
```

I've checked the redis dir path and the write permission is there.

here is my redis conf.

Redis configuration file example

```
daemonize yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 0

loglevel debug
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis.log"

databases 1
####   save ""
save 9000 1
save 3000 10
save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes

rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes

dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/redis/6379

slave-serve-stale-data yes
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec

no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64

set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64

hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes

client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60

hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

Comment: Check if you have enough free disk space - that is the common cause for this error message.

Comment: Ya, I've checked. Only 30% have been used on the partition

Answer (score -1):

Only the user who needs access to Redis has permission to read its data, and its database. This is the default user, the user Redis. Redis data directory must be owned by Redis.

[Option one](https://en-us.help.blackboard.com/Learn/Building_Blocks/Redis_Cache/Administrator/Redis_Cache_Basics_for_Administrators#install_server) (Paragraph 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) or [Option two](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04)(step 6)

Comment: Can you please summarize what is linked to so that this answer still makes sense when the links break? If you reply back when that's done, I will look again and remove the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: If this was an attempt to summarize, please *edit* the [answer to include this information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so that we don't have useful information lost in comments. (When all of this is done, I'll be deleting the my comments as they are no longer relevant.)